# Is there a easy way to make cloth with this type of details(like lace) at the edges?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, cloth-simulation

REFERENCE PICTURE:
[image]

Could you enlighten me with some technique or the tool with which I can achieve those details that are indicated in the image like maybe lace at the end of the umbrella.
And once a part is achieved there is some way of repeating the pattern.
A big thank you in advance.

Any way to repeat that process around the model.
https://sketchfab.com/models/0ad160d8515949169e2f09e912879a20

Comment: Not sure which dynamic behaviour you are expecting but you could use vertex parent, maybe, have you tried? See https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#vertex-parent-from-object-mode

Comment: you can try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q06lPp2PNG4